# Does Kotlin have a way to delegate the implementation of an interface to another class?

Tags: android, kotlin

I am using one activity and three fragments for my application

Each fragment has an interface that is used to communicate with the logic

the activity implements this interface and calls the logic object (a persistent fragment) with the same arguments, so it looks something like this:

```
class Child : Fragment() {

     private fun userInteraction() {
          (activity as? ChildInteraction)?.askStuff()
     }

     interface ChildInteraction {
          fun askStuff():Unit
     }


}


class ParentActivity : AppCompatActivity(), ChildInteraction {

    override fun askStuff() {
        (supportFragmentManager.findFragmentByTag("LOGIC") as? ChildInteraction).askStuff()
    }
}


class LogicFragment : Fragment(), ChildInteraction {

     override fun askStuff() {
         //do some work here
     }

 }
```

the thing is, that each interaction has 5-10 methods in it, and all ParentActivity does is pass on the message, is there a way to simplify the passing along?

I know you can't do this in Java but I was hoping there is a way for Kotlin to do it

Comment: Check out https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/delegation.html#implementation-by-delegation :)

Comment: @stkent doesn't that require receiving the "delegate to" property as constructor arg? Unfortunately Activities can't do that. :(

Comment: not an answer to your specific question, but if you have control over the design, you might instead consider multicasting an event as an alternative (e.g. via a `BroadcastReceiver`, or an event bus, or Rx stream)

Comment: @stkent that's pretty much what I want, unfortunatelly the fragment is created or retrieved from the fragment manager during onCreate because it requires a context

Comment: @homerman the broadcast receiver idea is good, I've only used it in services up to now, but it will be interesting to use it for inter-fragment/activity communication, I'll give it a try on my next project

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look on [`setTargetFragment`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment#setTargetFragment(android.app.Fragment,%20int)) and [`getTargetFragment`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#getTargetFragment()). Here is an example of Fragment-to-Fragment communication:

```
interface ChildInteraction {
    companion object

    fun askStuff()
}

fun ChildInteraction.Companion.wrap(f: Fragment) = (f.targetFragment as? ChildInteraction)

class Child1 : Fragment() {

    private fun userInteraction() {
        ChildInteraction.wrap(this)?.askStuff()
    }
}

class Child2 : Fragment() {

    private fun userInteraction() {
        ChildInteraction.wrap(this)?.askStuff()
    }
}

class LogicFragment : Fragment(), ChildInteraction {

    override fun askStuff() {
        //do some work here
    }
}

class ParentActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        val logic ...

        val child1 ...
        child1.setTargetFragment(logic, 0)

        val child2 ...
        child2.setTargetFragment(logic, 0)
    }
}
```

Comment: yeah that seems to work, though this seems to keep a reference to my logic in both the fragmentmanager of the activity and the child fragment, but I guess if I remove the targetrfagment when the child is destroyed and `isRemoving` it should be quite safe, thank you

Comment: unfortunatelly there seems to be the extra problem where the fragment manager that houses the logic fragment has to be the same as the child's fragment manager but I'll figure out a solution, thanks

Comment: `set/getTargetFragment` was deprecated in API 28. I think we should use Fragment Result API instead.

Answer (score 0):

Now I know that this is probably what works for me, so I'll be still accepting the other answer, and because it taught me something I didn't know.

But after some work the way that I handled it was this:

The fragment that attaches looks like this:

```
class Child : Fragment() {

    private var parent: ChildInteraction? = null

    override fun onAttach(context: Context?) {
        super.onAttach(context)
        //this should throw an exception if it is not implemented correctly
        parent = (context as LogicProvider).logic!! as Child.ChildInteraction
    }

    private fun userInteraction() {
        parent!!.askStuff()
    }

    interface ChildInteraction {
        fun askStuff():Unit
    }
}
```

Then I have the `LogicProvider` interface like this:

```
interface LogicProvider {
    val logic: Any?
}
```

and then the parent will implement logic providers that will pass on the arguments

```
class ParentActivity : AppCompatActivity(), LogicProvider {
  override var logic: Logic? = null

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        var frag: Fragment? = supportFragmentManager.findFragmentByTag("parent_logic")
        if (frag == null) {
            frag = Logic()
            supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction().add(frag, "parent_logic").commitNow()
        }
        logic = frag as Logic
    }

    override fun onPause() {
        super.onPause()
        if (isFinishing)
            supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction().remove(supportFragmentManager.findFragmentByTag("parent_logic")).commitNow()
    }

}
```

that way the logic fragment is the only one that has to implement interfaces

```
class Logic : Fragment(), Child.ChildInteraction, Child2.ChildInteraction2 {
    override fun askStuff() {
        //do stuff here
    }
    override fun askStuff2() {
        //do other stuff here
    }

}
```